# Перегрузка методов с переменным числом параметров

Tags: java, перегрузка-операторов, методы

Почему такой способ перегрузки метода с переменным числом параметров является недопустимым?

```
void methodName(Integer ... args) { }
void methodName(Integer[ ] args) { }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По факту, переменное число аргументов ничто иное, как просто украшение синтаксиса – это всего-лишь массив передаваемых данных, в данном случае целых чисел.

А написав потом

```
void methodName(Integer[ ] args) { }
```

вы фактически дублируете сигнатуру один в один. Один метод раскрывается в передачу массива целых чисел и другой.

Два метода с одинаковой сигнатурой - не могут существовать в одном классе.

Внутри Java своими механизмами вертит этим синтаксическим сахаром под названием `Integer...`:  смотрит количество аргументов, их тип, и создает динамически массив переданного типа, размером `N`. Т..e. в итоге методу передастся `new Integer[] {num1, num2, num3, num3, и т.д.};`, ровно также, как это придется делать и во втором случае

Comment: Если объявить метод таким образом:
    void methodName(Integer[ ] args) { },
то его нельзя будет вызвать так:
    methodName(1,2,3,4);

Comment: @jisecayeyo Потому, что внутри своими механизмами `Integer...` в начале смотрит количество аргументов, их тип, и создает массив переданного типа, размером `N`. Т..e. в итоге методу передастся `new Integer[] {num1, num2, num3, num3, и т.д.};` ровно также, как это придется делать и во втором случае.. Только во втором вы сами руками делаете, а в первом за вас все сделают....синтаксический сахар это......но смысл не меняется. сигнатура останется такой же

Answer (score 1):

потому что `Integer...` и `Integer[]` равнозначны, и являются массивами.